# Touchscroll using Prototype

Tags: javascript, mobile, jquery-mobile, prototypejs

I'm developing a mobile site. I want to incorporate a touch scroll area of the page with fixed header and footer areas.

I tried iScroll 4, but it gave problems when using early versions of Android.

The following solution works very well with iOS: 
   http://neave.github.com/touch-scroll/footer.html

Would you be able to suggest a solution that will deliver this functionality for Android phones?

Answer (score 0):

From JQuery Mobile's doc site:

> **Scroll events**
>
> **scrollstart**
>       Triggers when a scroll begins. Note that iOS devices freeze DOM
>   manipulation during scroll, queuing
>   them to apply when the scroll
>   finishes. We're currently
>   investigating ways to allow DOM
>   manipulations to apply before a scroll
>   starts.
>
> **scrollstop**
>       Triggers when a scroll finishes.

Look [here for more information](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/#docs/api/events.html)

I haven't been able to find a good example. You can look at `$.mobile.silentScroll` or `$.mobile.slider` [here](http://jquerymobiledictionary.dyndns.org/#/dict.html)